# Url Rewrite in a different way

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting

I am used to rewriting links like this:

http://example.com/**category**/banking-jobs :: RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/$ category.php?id=$1 [L]

where category is fixed ie.a part of the url is fixed.

I realized am **not** good at rewrite at all when i ran into a rewrite with no fixed part eg.

http://example.com/year/month/post-name

this means that the year, month, post-name can b anything.

Please how can i go about this

EDIT:

i have another scenario i have another url structure (http://example.com/year/month/day) similar to: http://example.com/year/month/post-name

but they are meant to be handled seperately. how do i achieve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use placeholders `([^/]+)` like in your original example.

```
      RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/$ category.php?id=$1 [L]
                      ^        ^
corresponds to        |        |
                      |        |
http://example.com/category/banking-jobs
```

So for an URL like:

```
 http://example.com/year/month/day/post-name
```

You would use:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ category.php?$1,$2,$3
```

And anything that's in `(` parenthesis `)` will add another enumerated `$4` which you then use in the rewriten filename as `&param=$2` placeholder.

Comment: i have other rewrite rules in my .htaccess; will this overwrite them eg. i have : RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/$ category.php?id=$1 [L] ... will it overwrite it

Comment: Just add the `[L]` flag for each of them. Then it's ensured that only one of them is applied at any time. Best way to avoid such issues.

Comment: @mario, thanks. i have another scenario i have another url structure (http://example.com/year/month/day) similar to: http://example.com/year/month/post-name

but they are meant to be handled seperately. how do i achieve it

Comment: It's often sufficient to order the most specific rule first. Otherwise you need to specialize them. Use `(\d+)` for all-numeric placeholders, or .e.g `([\w\d.-]+)` a specific character class.

Comment: @mario, pls can u make d numeric placeholders clearer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)/(.+)/(.+)$ category.php?y=$1&m=$2&d=$3&post=$4 [L]
```